# Add formula in Excel cells then loop through other tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I want to:

1. Add a formula to specific column (column T)
2. Loop through different tabs and add formula from 1.
3. Filter all those columns descending.

The code only runs on the first sheet.

```
Dim N As Long
Dim wsName As String

For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name

    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then
        'command
        Call blank
        Call hide

    Else 'do nothing

    End If
Next N

Sub blank()
    Range("T2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]<>"""",RC[-2]="""",""FALSE"")"
    Range("T2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T6999")
End Sub

Sub hide()
    Columns("T:T").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I'm not sure you need two separate procedures, but anyway one approach is to add a worksheet parameter to the subs you are calling.

2) Your code never changed the active sheet which by default is what is operated on; hence only the first sheet worked.

3) I suggest reading this [How to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?s=1%7C267.0816).

```
Sub x()

Dim N As Long
Dim wsName As String

For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name
    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then
        'command
        blank wsName
        hide wsName
    End If
Next N

End Sub

Sub blank(s As String)

Worksheets(s).Range("T2:T6999").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]<>"""",RC[-2]="""",""FALSE"")"

End Sub

Sub hide(s As String)

Worksheets(s).Columns("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I received an error when adding the wsName. Error is below.                                             Compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.                       I tried to use call blank (wsName) as well and same error.

Comment: Works for me. On which line?

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it works. I'll go over the suggested reading. thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Perhaps you could get in the habit of accepting answers - you don't seem to have done so so far?